# How to pass variable from php for() to ajax when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

when clicking （.refresh）button、how would you pass $data_name to ajax which you'll get by for() in body field of php script?
I would like to pass the variable for selecting data from database.

```
2Scripts:
(1) html formated .php file>
ajax written in header field,
php for() written in body field
(2) SQL select script in php, added 
$dataname= $_POST['dataname'];
```

In for() I'm getting data from DB and showing data tables, DATA　A～C.
When clicking the button for each data, I would want to get the new data from data base.
I was able to get it, just writting "A" for Ajax, but I would want to pass variable for many tables.
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpJ7B.png

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.refresh').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        // 通信先ファイル名
        url: "select.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({"data_name": $data_name}),
        success: function(data) {
        //more code
        },
        error: function(data) {         
        //more code
        }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
        //more code　for(){　 getting $data_name（A、B、C）here >
        echo <<<EOD
        <button class='refresh'>REFRESH DATA</button>
        <table class='show'></table>
EOD;
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking - is there one button or multiple (in the for)?  You could do `<button class='refresh' data-name='$data_name'>REFRESH DATA</button>` (or however you put php variables in HTML) then `$.ajax({ data: $(this).data("name")..`

Comment: Where is `$data_name` coming from in the ajax ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Multiple button will show cuz I've written button in  the for(), where I also get $data_name(from select SQL script from other php). I was able to solve this problem by your comment , using data-name and then writting $(this).data("name") in .ajax. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different PHP to return the JSON or the same.
So if you want to use the same script you basically want to send a JSON with the data when your PHP script gets a POST.
So you have to check:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     // The request comes from Javascript doing POST
     // Query Database and return a JSON with the field "data_name"
} else {
     // Render your form like now you're doing now, the request com from the browser loading the page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//select.php
<?php 
 $data= $_POST["data_name"];

 echo  json_encode( $data);
?>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.refresh').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        // 通信先ファイル名
        url: "select.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({"data_name": $data_name}),
        success: function(data) {
        
         // getting $data_name（A、B、C）here


        },
        error: function(data) {         
        //more code
        }
});
</script>
```